# Fixed page height with bootsprap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fix the height of the page, that page does not have scroll.
I use bootstrap for create layouts. I have a two column with the same width. And when column have many content then this column should have a scrollbar.

And i use next css styles:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#right {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5z7wemz/)

But this not have effect. How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `overflow: auto;`?

Answer (score 0):

First off, since this css will be common to both the left and right columns, it's worth giving them both a class (eg: `.column`).

You can use the `max-height` and `overflow-y` properties to achieve this:

```
.column {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that You can use the viewport measurement units in CSS3.

**[Viewport-Percentage](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)**

You can also refer to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zkmcqj64/) .

There is also an other example .

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid wrapper">

  <div class="row-fluid columns content"> 

    <div class="span2 article-tree">
      navigation column
    </div>

    <div class="span10 content-area">
      content column 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
     footer content
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
    background-color: #C9E6FF;
    height: 100%;   
}

.content-area, .article-tree{
    background: #bada55;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Here's the original post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179166/htmlcss-twitter-bootstrap-full-page-layout-or-height-100-npx?rq=1)