# bootstrap full witdh and height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a bootstrap newbie. I am trying to create a layout with full width and height. I need to have two divs, one as the header and the bottom one will have the content to fill the entire space below the header.
What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Please see the following post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179166/htmlcss-twitter-bootstrap-full-page-layout-or-height-100-npx

Comment: Use CSS to set the heights. Example: http://codeply.com/go/1I41vs3sMU