# Sections Height with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i wish to have the website fitting the page with no scrolling.
I've 3 sections : header, section and footer
i tried to test this:
row-lg-1 for the header and the footer and row-lg-10 for the section, but it doesn't works, any idea ?
So finally it's the "section" who must be resized automatically

PS : it must be done with bootstrap

My code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>La maison de l'architecte</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Le site de la maison de l'architecture">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">

      /* Styles de base */
      body {
        font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
        background-color: #eef;
        color: #259;
      }
      nav img {
        width: 100%;
      }

      /* Styles pour les smartphones */
      #left, #side1, #side2 {
        padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
      }

      /* Styles pour les tablettes */
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        #left{
          padding: 0;
        }
        #side1 {
          padding: 10px 5px 0 0;
        }
        #side2 {
          padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
        }
      }

      /* Styles pour les écrans moyens et grands */
      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        #side1, #side2 {
          padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/maison.png" alt="logo" class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"></a>
      <h1 class="text-center">La maison de l'architecte</h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="">
      <div id="left" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/city1.jpg" alt="Nos réalisations"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="side1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/side1.jpg" alt="Nos projets"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="side2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/side2.jpg" alt="Notre ambition"></a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <footer class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-spotify fa-2x"></i></a>
    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I Google `section fill entire page bootstrap` I seem to be seeing useful results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML&CSS + Twitter Bootstrap: full page layout or height 100% - Npx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179166/htmlcss-twitter-bootstrap-full-page-layout-or-height-100-npx)

Comment: for the moment i haven't found a correct answer

Comment: Is the link above not helpful? Why?

Comment: Sorry no, i checked it but it didn't helped. Could my code be helpfull ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that you can use some classes from Bootstrap to do this. However, you can achieve it by a little bit of jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
         var curHeight = $(window).height();

         $("header").height((curHeight * 0.3) + "px");

         $("nav").height((curHeight * 0.6) + "px");

         $("footer").height((curHeight * 0.1) + "px");
    });
});
```

With this code, you will have 30% of viewport to `header`, 60% for `nav`, and 10% for `footer`. you can easily change these numbers at your will as long as they adds up to 1. 
Additionally, you need well-known `clearfix` class for your `nav` section since you have different images of different height in different columns. It will make sure that the height of `nav` is equal to the largest column's height inside `nav`:

**HTML**

```
 <nav class="clearfix">
```

**CSS**

```
 .clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
  }
  .clearfix { display: inline-block; }
   /* start commented backslash hack \*/
   * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
   .clearfix { display: block; }
   /* close commented backslash hack */
```

You can read more about `clearfix` in [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Comment: Could this work with a responsive design too ? Cause i'm not sure, i think i'll try the 2 ways.

Comment: @webdev: It should because it reacts on every window resize event.

Comment: finally i don't need to use it but thanks anyway (i know for what clearfix is) but now i've another problem...